# How to determine step size for this program

Tags: python

So the basis of this assignment is to make a python program that generates a logarithmic table.
We're given steps of functions we need to make in order to execute the program. I haven't gotten very far and I would would appreciate some help.

A function that prompts the user for the step size and returns it to
the calling statement. Function also deals with range checking to make
sure that step size provided is greater than 0.

Here's my code so far

```
  def min(): 
          return int(input("What's your minimum value"))
  def check(): 
          if min >= 0 
             return print("ERROR. Minimum should be greater than 0" 
          else: 
             return min 


    def max(): 
            return int(input("What's your maximum value? ")

    def max_Check(): 
            if max <= min 
                return print(f"ERROR. Maximum should be greater than {min})
```

Comment: Please only ask one question at a time. [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Oh sorry my bad, Ill redo it

Comment: Please take the [tour], read [what's on-topic here](/help/on-topic), [ask],
and the [question checklist](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260648/843953). Please make an attempt at your other functions and ask a _specific_ question with a [mre] if you run into a problem. If you're asking if your first two functions are correct, we don't know. Why don't you run some tests and tell us? Also note that your title must summarize your _actual question_.

Comment: Don't use `min` and `max` as your function names. There are built-in functions with these names and you're replacing them.

Comment: Your `check` and `max_Check` functions need parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> A function that **prompts** the user for the step size and **returns** it to the calling statement. Function also deals with range checking to make sure that step size provided is greater than 0

Your assignment wants you to write a function that'll ask the user for the step size. If it's < 0, it should complain (and possibly ask again, see [Asking the user for input until they give a valid response](//stackoverflow.com/q/23294658/843953)).

Note: You shouldn't use `min` and `max` as function names because they are already defined in python.

```
def get_step():
    while True:
        try:
            x = float(input("Enter a step size: "))
            if x <= 0:
                print("Must enter a value greater than 0.")
                continue
            return x
        except ValueError:
            print("Invalid number. Please try again.")
```

To use it, you'd do something like this:

```
step_size = get_step()
```

Now, `step_size` contains the value that the user entered.

Similarly, they want a function that asks the user for a min value.

```
min_value = get_min()
```

And also a max value. Remember that the max value function takes an argument (the previously entered minimum value), and checks that the entered number is greater than *that* minimum value. This function would look something like this:

```
def get_max(min_val):
    # The function body is an exercise for you
    # Hint: Use min_val when checking if the given number is greater

max_value = get_max(min_value)
```

You could probably generalize all these three functions as a single function if it takes the message and the lower bound as an argument:

```
def get_number(msg, min_val):
    # How would you adapt the function to use msg and min_val?
```

And use it like so:

```
min_value = get_number("Enter a min value: ", 0)
max_value = get_number("Enter a max value: ", min_value)
step_value = get_number("Enter a step size: ", 0)
```

Comment: Ok so since the get_max needs an argument do I put the get_min for that function or for the function used to check if the max value is greater than the min value?

Comment: You'd give the _value_ returned by `get_min()` as an argument to `get_max()`. @Kayla

Comment: Thank you, I have another question about a function as well. Would it be ok to type it here in the comments??

Comment: If it's related to your original question, [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71073874/edit) your question. If not, ask a new question.

Comment: Its about calling the functions I used to check for min and max. How would I do that?

Comment: Not sure I understand what you mean. If you defined your `get_min()` function the way I showed, you simply do `min_value = get_min()` like I mentioned in the answer. You don't really need a separate function to check for min and max, since according to your assignment brief, the functions that ask the user for those values are supposed to check it. It might be useful for you to redo a good tutorial on functions?